# Google Realtime API Debugger doesn't work with InMemoryDocument?

Tags: google-drive-realtime-api

The symptoms are that with an in-memory document, the debugger comes up blank, and the following warnings are reported by chrome's developer tools:

> /deep/ combinator is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120 for more details.
>
> debugger.html?ids=:10766 Calling Element.createShadowRoot() for an element which already hosts a shadow root is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4668884095336448 for more details.
>
> ::shadow pseudo-element is deprecated. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/6750456638341120 for more details.

...which is a shame, as there are some behaviors which differ between a server-backed document and an in-memory one, and so the debugger would actually be pretty helpful.

In addition, when you attempt to close the (blank) debugger, it stays open and the following alert pops up:

> The page at https://www.gstatic.com says:
> Unknown target origin, cannot post

Any workarounds to this?

Answer (score 1):

Currently there is no workaround for this. The debugger has not been implemented to work with in-memory documents. I will update this question should it change in the future.